# Drop down value not appearing properly in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am quite new to MVC and I am creating a static dropdown in a view file something like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Category", new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                       new SelectListItem {Text = "hi" , Value= "hello"},
                       new SelectListItem {Text = "hi#" , Value= "helloC#"},
                      new SelectListItem {Text = "test" , Value= "test1"}
                    },"Select data")
```

[image: This is the first example]

[image: When I hover]

but in UI I am getting the drop down but the drop down shows blank value, however when I hover on any item of the dropdown the value appears. Main point is value in the drop down get's displayed only when mouse is hovered on the value. Pretty strange.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more. It is not quite clear what you are asking here. In HTML dropdowns do not change values when hovered with the mouse unless you write some javascript for it. In ASP.NET MVC the `@Html.DropDownList` helper simply generates a standard HTML `<select>` element.

Comment: just attached the screenshots

Comment: trying with other Browser, does it acts the same way?

Comment: You have styled the color and the background-color the same!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a style issue?  Check your css.  Use the chrome dev tools to see what is applying the hidden or color:white attribute?  Also disable java script and then you can rule that out :)